# How can I launch the registration page using @auth0/auth0-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, auth0

I've been stuck trying to get the sign up page (registration) to launch by default using `@auth0/auth0-react`. In the past, I used to send `mode` which used to work in `auth0-js`.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
 const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
 loginWithRedirect({
      // screen_hint: 'signUp'
      screen_hint: 'signup',
      ui_locales: 'es',
    });
```

How can I make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://community.auth0.com/t/can-not-get-screen-hint-to-work/46519, the problem is that in the Admin panel I have selected the classic experience, whereas these parameters only work for the new experience.

Nonetheless, you can pass any arbitrary variable and it will be sent as a GET parameter. Therefore, we can pass our traditional `mode` and it will work:

```
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  loginWithRedirect({
      screen_hint: 'signup',
      ui_locales: 'es',
      mode: 'signUp',
    });
```

Check if you have the classic or new experience in your dashboard by going to:

- Branding -> Universal Login
  [image]

[image]

As you can see, I had the classic experience enabled.